# Swift: Detecting swipe gestures compatible with iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this code to detect swipe gestures:

```
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("rightSwiped"))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.matn.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("leftSwiped"))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.matn.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("downSwiped"))
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    self.matn.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("upSwiped"))
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
    self.matn.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

func rightSwiped(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("right swiped ")
}

func leftSwiped()
{
    println("left swiped ")
}

func downSwiped()
{
    println("down swiped ")
}

func upSwiped()
{
    println("Up swiped ")
}
```

[image]
But `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection` is available in iOS8 and later. How can I make it compatible with iOS7 ?

Comment: Direction has been available since 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wain mentioned into comment that `Direction has been available since 3.2` so you can use it with iOS 7. I have tested your code and its working fine with `Deployment target 7.0`. so you can use it with iOS 7.